# Adding a sidebar without changing alignment of main content

Tags: html, css

I have a header, footer, and main content on a site. Currently, they have auto margins and are all the same width so they all center together on the page nicely.

On some but not all pages on the site, I want a sidebar to appear next to the main content. I want the main content to still be aligned with the header and footer, and everything to remain the same width, but with the sidebar appearing to the right of the main content. In other words, everything else should be as similar as possible to when there is no sidebar.
So with sidebar it should be like this:

```
   |HEADER |
   |CONTENT| |SB|
   |CONTENT| |SB|
   |CONTENT|
   |FOOTER |
```

And without sidebar:

```
   |HEADER |
   |CONTENT|
   |CONTENT|
   |CONTENT|
   |FOOTER |
```

Is there an easy way to do this with CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the sidebar `position` property and one of the following values:

> - fixed
> - relative
> - absolute

and `z-index: 1` (or higher value). This will take the sidebar out of the normal "flow" (except `relative` *technically*).

**REFERENCES**

- [Positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)
- [Calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

Review the Snippet in Full page mode for a better view (although the demo is responsive so it still functions in a smaller viewport). Click the red <kbd>**Toggle**</kbd> button. Further details are commented in Snippet below.

**SNIPPET 1**

```js
// This is not required; it's for demonstration

var toggle = document.getElementById('sideToggle');

toggle.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var sidebar = document.querySelector('aside');
  sidebar.classList.toggle('off');
}, false);
```

```css
* {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  font: 400 16px/1.45 Arial;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-color: lime;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
header {
  border-color: #fff;
}
main {
  width: 70vw;
  padding: 3em 5vw;
  border: 5px dotted blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
article {
  padding: 1em 2em;
  border-color: salmon;
}
p {
  border-color: transparent;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
a {
  background: yellow;
}
/* Demo */

#sideToggle {
  float: right;
  font: inherit;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 4em;
}
/* Required styles are preceded by ✎ */

#sidebar {
  /* ✎ Use absolute or relative if "sticky"
  || behavior is not desired. Relative
  || will poisition itself relative to it's
  || original position. Absolute will
  || position itself in relation to the 
  || nearest positioned element, so it's
  || easier to use relative since you'll
  || need another positioned element to
  || position the sidebar. See reference
  || for more details.
  */
  position: fixed;
  /* ✎ See reference */
  z-index: 1;
  /* ✎ See reference */
  top: calc(50vh - 35px);
  /* ✎ See reference */
  right: 0;
  width: 20vw;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 70px;
  border: dashed red;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}
/* Demo */

.off {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <button id='sideToggle'>Toggle</button>
    <hgroup>
      <h1>H1 Title</h1>
      <h2>H2 Title</h2>
    </hgroup>

    <nav>
      <a href='#sec1'>Section 1</a>
      <a href='#sec2'>Section 2</a>
      <a href='#sec3'>Section 3</a>
    </nav>

  </header>


  <main>
    <!--BEGIN SIDEBAR-->
    <aside id='sidebar'>
      <h3>Sidebar</h3>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href='#' target='_self'>Home Page</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href='http://example.com'>External Site</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href='#/'>Site Directory</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </aside>
    <!--END SIDEBAR-->
    <section id='sec1'>
      <article>
        <p>
          Chaugnar Faugn ph'grah'n Chaugnar Faugn wgah'n r'luh y-nglui Cthulhu ch', Nyarlathotep gotha mg hrii nog Nyarlathotep, llll goka uln uh'eagl Cthulhu sll'ha. Ph's'uhn Yoggoth Dagon gnaiih geb ebunma kadishtu n'ghft, nnnkadishtu Shub-Niggurath shtunggli
          nglui nnnuln tharanak ooboshu, ehyeog nnnHastur ya ep y-Chaugnar Faugn nogyar. Mg gotha Dagon naflr'luh f'ilyaa ftaghu s'uhn ooboshu f'ah Dagon, ehye athg fhtagnyar uaaah gnaiih phlegeth ah stell'bsna ngAzathoth, uln h''bthnk uaaahoth Cthulhu
          llll ngnglui bug y'hahor. Llll orr'eyar gof'nn Tsathoggua naflhrii Cthulhu shogg vulgtm naflkn'a lw'nafh nnnn'ghft, zhro ngn'ghft f'shogg r'luh f'Nyarlathotep chtenff bug syha'h naflchtenff naflkadishtu, cvulgtlagln stell'bsna zhro natharanak
          uaaah throd 'bthnk ngebunma bug.
        </p>
        <p>
          Wgah'n shogg hafh'drn ep y'hah kn'aoth ngtharanak shtunggli ee zhro wgah'n r'luh, nw ilyaa vulgtm zhro wgah'n k'yarnak ftaghu uaaah uln stell'bsnaog. Fm'latgh gotha f'stell'bsna stell'bsna y-uln gotha kadishtuagl gnaiih, Dagon h'chtenff sll'ha bug mg
          hupadgh cuh'e s'uhn, ah ebunma uaaah lloig y'hah Cthulhu. Uln ah wgah'n gof'nn ph'Azathoth hupadgh y-shogg, gof'nn ngn'gha kn'a ilyaa kadishtu, nanw fhtagn ah gotha mnahn'. Nghupadgh shtunggliagl n'gha czhro Yoggothog naflathg mg ch'or ehye
          vulgtlagln f's'uhn f'llll, ph'grah'n f'lw'nafh fm'latgh y'hah lw'nafhnyth ph'Azathoth nw Tsathoggua Cthulhu wgah'n, 'ai fm'latgh stell'bsna naflnglui naYoggoth 'aioth kadishtu nog r'luh f'ebunma.
        </p>
        <p>
          Sgn'wahl naflHastur sll'ha nnntharanak kn'a li'hee y-fhtagn, hupadgh bug y'hah Yoggoth Azathoth nw, orr'e y'hah stell'bsna f'syha'h syha'h. Naflooboshu k'yarnak shagg Shub-Niggurath shagg llll f'shugg nagnaiih, sgn'wahl s'uhn y'hah grah'n nasll'ha zhro
          cnilgh'ri hafh'drn, fm'latghyar ngsll'ha lw'nafh Azathoth llll cgof'nn. R'lyehog ch' y-mg gnaiih ngnw hrii vulgtm hai, athg naflhrii n'gha goka hrii uh'e, wgah'n ebunma uaaah s'uhn tharanak 'fhalma. 'bthnkor Dagon ph'llll fhtagn uh'e Dagon gnaiih
          f'shagg hafh'drn 'fhalma, vulgtlagln f'bug hai 'fhalma 'ai y'hahagl h'syha'h ya naflshagg llll, Chaugnar Faugn k'yarnak orr'e ph'gnaiih ph'nw tharanak ph'nglui ilyaa.
        </p>
        <p>
          Sll'haagl vulgtlagln uh'eog nnnmnahn' h'llll Shub-Niggurath ngthrod wgah'n ronyar hrii, h''ai tharanak zhro 'ai bug nachtenff ngluiog. Ebunma n'ghft chtenff gof'nn Dagon ron ilyaa hupadghoth, ep stell'bsna Shub-Niggurath nglui h'vulgtlagln phlegeth hupadgh
          li'hee, zhro Cthulhu uaaah vulgtlagln ee phlegeth. Nalw'nafh sgn'wahl kn'a chupadgh hrii ph'wgah'n grah'n f'n'gha Shub-Niggurathyar, 'fhalma nog ch' sgn'wahl Azathoth throd gotha n'gha, hafh'drn cs'uhn throd cshugg phlegeth s'uhn shtunggli.
          Fhtagn Cthulhu Azathothor Cthulhu Nyarlathotep ebunmaoth nafluln 'fhalma hai ngah, Azathoth shtunggli ch'agl f'nw naathg bug shagg nog Tsathoggua cgotha, nabug shtunggli mg ilyaa Dagon hafh'drn r'luh ep.
        </p>
        <p>
          Chaugnar Faugn gothaoth Nyarlathotep ron ep athg 'bthnk s'uhn phlegeth chai, syha'h sll'ha ph'Dagon f'nilgh'ri Chaugnar Faugn n'gha hlirghyar nglui, kn'a n'gha shagg hrii ebunma Tsathogguayar nnngoka f'nw. Geb orr'e kadishtu chtenffor shtunggli h'nog
          chtenffagl hrii gnaiih uln, fhtagn chtenff orr'eagl uln chtenff n'ghanyth hafh'drn ebunma Tsathoggua sll'ha, ron y-Yoggoth Cthulhu vulgtm uln ngR'lyeh Cthulhu ngehye. Y'hah bugyar wgah'n Azathoth zhro shtunggli f'shugg f'ftaghu ngathg geb shtunggli
          nachtenff naflli'hee, phlegeth Dagon n'gha ebunma throd r'luh gotha ngah sll'ha nglui. Lw'nafh ph'geb kn'a uln naYoggoth ebunma r'luh phlegeth Cthulhu ehye corr'e 'ai, Tsathoggua shagg ron f'nglui shagg li'hee goka wgah'n y-r'luh orr'e stell'bsna,
          nogog ngCthulhu mg nglui shugg fm'latgh h'hai hupadgh goka llll.
        </p>
        <p>
          S'uhn ee chtenff y-stell'bsna y-sgn'wahl athg hlirgh cAzathoth, Nyarlathotep Tsathoggua ebunma orr'e vulgtm Hastur, phlegethagl naflnog athg 'fhalma throd mnahn'.
        </p>
      </article>
    </section>
    <section id='sec2'>
      <article>
        <p>One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided
          by arches into stiff sections. The bedding was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment.</p>

        <p>His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. "What's happened to me? " he thought. It wasn't a dream. His room, a proper human room although a little too small, lay peacefully between
          its four familiar walls.</p>

        <p>A collection of textile samples lay spread out on the table - Samsa was a travelling salesman - and above it there hung a picture that he had recently cut out of an illustrated magazine and housed in a nice, gilded frame. It showed a lady fitted
          out with a fur hat and fur boa who sat upright, raising a heavy fur muff that covered the whole of her lower arm towards the viewer.</p>

        <p>Gregor then turned to look out the window at the dull weather. Drops of rain could be heard hitting the pane, which made him feel quite sad. "How about if I sleep a little bit longer and forget all this nonsense", he thought, but that was something
          he was unable to do because he was used to sleeping on his right, and in his present state couldn't get into that position. However hard he threw himself onto his right, he always rolled back to where he was.</p>

        <p>He must have tried it a hundred times, shut his eyes so that he wouldn't have to look at the floundering legs, and only stopped when he began to feel a mild, dull pain there that he had never felt before. "Oh, God", he thought, "what a strenuous
          career it is that I've chosen! Travelling day in and day out. Doing business like this takes much more effort than doing your own business at home, and on top of that there's the curse of travelling, worries about making train connections, bad
          and irregular food, contact with different people all the time so that you can never get to know anyone or become friendly with them. It can all go to Hell! " He felt a slight itch</p>
      </article>
    </section>
    <section id='sec3'>
      <article>
        <p>"Lost by a whale! Young man, come nearer to me: it was devoured, chewed up, crunched by the monstrousest parmacetty that ever chipped a boat!&mdash;ah, ah!"</p>

        <p>I was a little alarmed by his energy, perhaps also a little touched at the hearty grief in his concluding exclamation, but said as calmly as I could, "What you say is no doubt true enough, sir; but how could I know there was any peculiar ferocity
          in that particular whale, though indeed I might have inferred as much from the simple fact of the accident."</p>

        <p>"Look ye now, young man, thy lungs are a sort of soft, d'ye see; thou dost not talk shark a bit. SURE, ye've been to sea before now; sure of that?"</p>

        <p>"Sir," said I, "I thought I told you that I had been four voyages in the merchant&mdash;"</p>

        <p>"Hard down out of that! Mind what I said about the marchant service&mdash;don't aggravate me&mdash;I won't have it. But let us understand each other. I have given thee a hint about what whaling is; do ye yet feel inclined for it?"</p>
      </article>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <nav>
      <a href='#sec1'>Section 1</a>
      <a href='#sec2'>Section 2</a>
      <a href='#sec3'>Section 3</a>
    </nav>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

**SNIPPET 2**

```js
// This is not required; it's for demonstration

var toggle = document.getElementById('sideToggle');
var expand = document.getElementById('expand');
var reduce = document.getElementById('reduce');
var counter = 0;

toggle.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var sidebar = document.querySelector('aside');
  sidebar.classList.toggle('off');
}, false);

expand.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var sec1 = document.querySelector('#sec1');
  counter += 5;
  sec1.style.marginLeft = counter + 'px';
  sec1.style.marginRight = counter + 'px';
}, false);

reduce.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var sec1 = document.querySelector('#sec1');
  counter -= 5;
  sec1.style.marginLeft = counter + 'px';
  sec1.style.marginRight = counter + 'px';
}, false);
```

```css
* {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  font: 400 16px/1.45 Arial;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-color: lime;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
header {
  border-color: #fff;
}
main {
  width: 70vw;
  padding: 3em 5vw;
  border: 5px dotted blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
article {
  padding: 1em 2em;
  border-color: salmon;
}
p {
  border-color: transparent;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
a {
  background: yellow;
}
/* Demo */

#sideToggle,
#expand,
#reduce {
  float: right;
  font: inherit;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 4em;
}
/* Required styles are preceded by ✎ */

/* Styles that have been changed are preceded by ✦ */

#sidebar {
  /* ✎ Use absolute or relative if "sticky"
  || behavior is not desired. Relative
  || will position itself relative to it's
  || original position. Absolute will
  || position itself in relation to the 
  || nearest positioned element, so it's
  || easier to use relative since you'll
  || need another positioned element to
  || position the sidebar. See reference
  || for more details.
  */
  /* ✦ */
  position: absolute;
  /* ✎ See reference */
  z-index: 1;
  /* ✦ See reference */
  top: 2%;
  /* ✦ See reference */
  right: -20vw;
  width: 20vw;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 70px;
  border: dashed red;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}
.off {
  display: none;
}
section {
  /* ✦ */
  box-sizing: content-box;
  /* ✦ */
  position: relative;
  /* ✦ */
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <button id='expand'>Expand</button>
    <button id='reduce'>Reduce</button>
    <button id='sideToggle'>Toggle</button>
    <hgroup>
      <h1>H1 Title</h1>
      <h2>H2 Title</h2>
    </hgroup>

    <nav>
      <a href='#sec1'>Section 1</a>
      <a href='#sec2'>Section 2</a>
      <a href='#sec3'>Section 3</a>
    </nav>

  </header>


  <main id='main'>

    <!--SIDEBAR IS MOVED INTO #SEC1-->
    <section id='sec1'>
      <!--BEGIN SIDEBAR-->
      <aside id='sidebar'>
        <h3>Sidebar</h3>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href='#' target='_self'>Home Page</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href='http://example.com'>External Site</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href='#/'>Site Directory</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </aside>
      <!--END SIDEBAR-->
      <article>
        <p>
          Chaugnar Faugn ph'grah'n Chaugnar Faugn wgah'n r'luh y-nglui Cthulhu ch', Nyarlathotep gotha mg hrii nog Nyarlathotep, llll goka uln uh'eagl Cthulhu sll'ha. Ph's'uhn Yoggoth Dagon gnaiih geb ebunma kadishtu n'ghft, nnnkadishtu Shub-Niggurath shtunggli
          nglui nnnuln tharanak ooboshu, ehyeog nnnHastur ya ep y-Chaugnar Faugn nogyar. Mg gotha Dagon naflr'luh f'ilyaa ftaghu s'uhn ooboshu f'ah Dagon, ehye athg fhtagnyar uaaah gnaiih phlegeth ah stell'bsna ngAzathoth, uln h''bthnk uaaahoth Cthulhu
          llll ngnglui bug y'hahor. Llll orr'eyar gof'nn Tsathoggua naflhrii Cthulhu shogg vulgtm naflkn'a lw'nafh nnnn'ghft, zhro ngn'ghft f'shogg r'luh f'Nyarlathotep chtenff bug syha'h naflchtenff naflkadishtu, cvulgtlagln stell'bsna zhro natharanak
          uaaah throd 'bthnk ngebunma bug.
        </p>
        <p>
          Wgah'n shogg hafh'drn ep y'hah kn'aoth ngtharanak shtunggli ee zhro wgah'n r'luh, nw ilyaa vulgtm zhro wgah'n k'yarnak ftaghu uaaah uln stell'bsnaog. Fm'latgh gotha f'stell'bsna stell'bsna y-uln gotha kadishtuagl gnaiih, Dagon h'chtenff sll'ha bug mg
          hupadgh cuh'e s'uhn, ah ebunma uaaah lloig y'hah Cthulhu. Uln ah wgah'n gof'nn ph'Azathoth hupadgh y-shogg, gof'nn ngn'gha kn'a ilyaa kadishtu, nanw fhtagn ah gotha mnahn'. Nghupadgh shtunggliagl n'gha czhro Yoggothog naflathg mg ch'or ehye
          vulgtlagln f's'uhn f'llll, ph'grah'n f'lw'nafh fm'latgh y'hah lw'nafhnyth ph'Azathoth nw Tsathoggua Cthulhu wgah'n, 'ai fm'latgh stell'bsna naflnglui naYoggoth 'aioth kadishtu nog r'luh f'ebunma.
        </p>
        <p>
          Sgn'wahl naflHastur sll'ha nnntharanak kn'a li'hee y-fhtagn, hupadgh bug y'hah Yoggoth Azathoth nw, orr'e y'hah stell'bsna f'syha'h syha'h. Naflooboshu k'yarnak shagg Shub-Niggurath shagg llll f'shugg nagnaiih, sgn'wahl s'uhn y'hah grah'n nasll'ha zhro
          cnilgh'ri hafh'drn, fm'latghyar ngsll'ha lw'nafh Azathoth llll cgof'nn. R'lyehog ch' y-mg gnaiih ngnw hrii vulgtm hai, athg naflhrii n'gha goka hrii uh'e, wgah'n ebunma uaaah s'uhn tharanak 'fhalma. 'bthnkor Dagon ph'llll fhtagn uh'e Dagon gnaiih
          f'shagg hafh'drn 'fhalma, vulgtlagln f'bug hai 'fhalma 'ai y'hahagl h'syha'h ya naflshagg llll, Chaugnar Faugn k'yarnak orr'e ph'gnaiih ph'nw tharanak ph'nglui ilyaa.
        </p>
        <p>
          Sll'haagl vulgtlagln uh'eog nnnmnahn' h'llll Shub-Niggurath ngthrod wgah'n ronyar hrii, h''ai tharanak zhro 'ai bug nachtenff ngluiog. Ebunma n'ghft chtenff gof'nn Dagon ron ilyaa hupadghoth, ep stell'bsna Shub-Niggurath nglui h'vulgtlagln phlegeth hupadgh
          li'hee, zhro Cthulhu uaaah vulgtlagln ee phlegeth. Nalw'nafh sgn'wahl kn'a chupadgh hrii ph'wgah'n grah'n f'n'gha Shub-Niggurathyar, 'fhalma nog ch' sgn'wahl Azathoth throd gotha n'gha, hafh'drn cs'uhn throd cshugg phlegeth s'uhn shtunggli.
          Fhtagn Cthulhu Azathothor Cthulhu Nyarlathotep ebunmaoth nafluln 'fhalma hai ngah, Azathoth shtunggli ch'agl f'nw naathg bug shagg nog Tsathoggua cgotha, nabug shtunggli mg ilyaa Dagon hafh'drn r'luh ep.
        </p>
        <p>
          Chaugnar Faugn gothaoth Nyarlathotep ron ep athg 'bthnk s'uhn phlegeth chai, syha'h sll'ha ph'Dagon f'nilgh'ri Chaugnar Faugn n'gha hlirghyar nglui, kn'a n'gha shagg hrii ebunma Tsathogguayar nnngoka f'nw. Geb orr'e kadishtu chtenffor shtunggli h'nog
          chtenffagl hrii gnaiih uln, fhtagn chtenff orr'eagl uln chtenff n'ghanyth hafh'drn ebunma Tsathoggua sll'ha, ron y-Yoggoth Cthulhu vulgtm uln ngR'lyeh Cthulhu ngehye. Y'hah bugyar wgah'n Azathoth zhro shtunggli f'shugg f'ftaghu ngathg geb shtunggli
          nachtenff naflli'hee, phlegeth Dagon n'gha ebunma throd r'luh gotha ngah sll'ha nglui. Lw'nafh ph'geb kn'a uln naYoggoth ebunma r'luh phlegeth Cthulhu ehye corr'e 'ai, Tsathoggua shagg ron f'nglui shagg li'hee goka wgah'n y-r'luh orr'e stell'bsna,
          nogog ngCthulhu mg nglui shugg fm'latgh h'hai hupadgh goka llll.
        </p>
        <p>
          S'uhn ee chtenff y-stell'bsna y-sgn'wahl athg hlirgh cAzathoth, Nyarlathotep Tsathoggua ebunma orr'e vulgtm Hastur, phlegethagl naflnog athg 'fhalma throd mnahn'.
        </p>
      </article>
    </section>
    <section id='sec2'>
      <article>
        <p>One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided
          by arches into stiff sections. The bedding was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment.</p>

        <p>His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. "What's happened to me? " he thought. It wasn't a dream. His room, a proper human room although a little too small, lay peacefully between
          its four familiar walls.</p>

        <p>A collection of textile samples lay spread out on the table - Samsa was a travelling salesman - and above it there hung a picture that he had recently cut out of an illustrated magazine and housed in a nice, gilded frame. It showed a lady fitted
          out with a fur hat and fur boa who sat upright, raising a heavy fur muff that covered the whole of her lower arm towards the viewer.</p>

        <p>Gregor then turned to look out the window at the dull weather. Drops of rain could be heard hitting the pane, which made him feel quite sad. "How about if I sleep a little bit longer and forget all this nonsense", he thought, but that was something
          he was unable to do because he was used to sleeping on his right, and in his present state couldn't get into that position. However hard he threw himself onto his right, he always rolled back to where he was.</p>

        <p>He must have tried it a hundred times, shut his eyes so that he wouldn't have to look at the floundering legs, and only stopped when he began to feel a mild, dull pain there that he had never felt before. "Oh, God", he thought, "what a strenuous
          career it is that I've chosen! Travelling day in and day out. Doing business like this takes much more effort than doing your own business at home, and on top of that there's the curse of travelling, worries about making train connections, bad
          and irregular food, contact with different people all the time so that you can never get to know anyone or become friendly with them. It can all go to Hell! " He felt a slight itch</p>
      </article>
    </section>
    <section id='sec3'>
      <article>
        <p>"Lost by a whale! Young man, come nearer to me: it was devoured, chewed up, crunched by the monstrousest parmacetty that ever chipped a boat!&mdash;ah, ah!"</p>

        <p>I was a little alarmed by his energy, perhaps also a little touched at the hearty grief in his concluding exclamation, but said as calmly as I could, "What you say is no doubt true enough, sir; but how could I know there was any peculiar ferocity
          in that particular whale, though indeed I might have inferred as much from the simple fact of the accident."</p>

        <p>"Look ye now, young man, thy lungs are a sort of soft, d'ye see; thou dost not talk shark a bit. SURE, ye've been to sea before now; sure of that?"</p>

        <p>"Sir," said I, "I thought I told you that I had been four voyages in the merchant&mdash;"</p>

        <p>"Hard down out of that! Mind what I said about the marchant service&mdash;don't aggravate me&mdash;I won't have it. But let us understand each other. I have given thee a hint about what whaling is; do ye yet feel inclined for it?"</p>
      </article>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <nav>
      <a href='#sec1'>Section 1</a>
      <a href='#sec2'>Section 2</a>
      <a href='#sec3'>Section 3</a>
    </nav>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This would work! But is there a way to have the sidebar 'hug' the main content instead of the right side of the view? I want to have the content remain the same width as you expand and just have the margins grow, so you get a horizontal scroll when the view gets too small to show both the content and the sidebar, and the sidebar stays with the main content as the margins grow to its right.

Comment: That's a peculiar layout. See Snippet 2

Answer (score 1):

Develop two classes in the style sheet for main division. 
Whenever you want sidebar along with main, use the width attribute to define main and sidebar.

Switch between the classes whenever you want the sidebar.
Refer the code below.

```css
    header, footer {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        background: #aaa;
        padding: 10px 0px;
    }
    section {
        width: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    section div {
        float: left;
    }
    .only-main, .main-with-sidebar {
        height: 200px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .only-main {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .main-with-sidebar {
        width: 70%;
        border: 1px solid green;
    }

    /************ For sidebar ***********/
    .sidebar {
        width: 29%;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .hide {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<header>
<h1>Header</h1>
</header>
<section>
    <div class="only-main">Main</div>
    <div class="sidebar hide">Sidebar</div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="main-with-sidebar">Main</div>
    <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
</section>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: This is good, but is there a way to make the Header/Footer the same size as Main when there is a sidebar? Also, ideally, Main (and the other sections) wouldn't change sizes when the sidebar is added

Comment: Yes, it can be done. You will have to constraint your layout using max-width attribute to all the main contents (header, main and footer) and then use sidebar outside the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the little bit, you can have a look at it.
For having sidebar attached to main division, you need to make section width 100% and set the main division at center.

Here, I am using absolute positioning for sidebar, so for that I need to put relative position first to the section style.

```css
header, footer {
    width: 60%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #aaa;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    margin: auto;
}
section {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
section div {
    float: left;
}
.only-main, .main-with-sidebar {
    height: 200px;
    width: 60%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 20%;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

/************ For sidebar ***********/
.sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 19%;
    left: 80%;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
<h1>Header</h1>
</header>
<section>
    <div class="only-main">Main</div>
    <div class="sidebar hide">Sidebar</div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="main-with-sidebar">Main</div>
    <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
</section>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```